# If a right adjoint to the product functor exists, must it be the diagonal?

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors

Let $C$ be a category with binary products. The product functor $\times : C^2 \to C$ is *right* adjoint to the diagonal $\Delta: C \to C^2$. If $C$ has biproducts, then $\times$ is also *left* adjoint to $\Delta$. But from the fact that $\times$ is left adjoint to some functor $R$, can we conclude that $R = \Delta$?

In the case of nullary products, the answer is yes: if the terminal object $1: C^0 \to C$ has a right adjoint $R$, there's only one functor $C \to C^0$, so of course $R$ coincides with the diagonal $\Delta$. So a terminal object is also initial as soon as the functor $1: C^0 \to C$ has a right adjoint.

To say that $\Delta$ is right adjoint to $\times$ is to say that $\times$ is also a coproduct functor. I believe that if the binary product is also a binary coproduct, this implies that the $C$ is canonically enriched in pointed sets, with the "0" points on the homsets providing the structure maps for the "identity matrix" natural isomorphism $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}: \amalg \Rightarrow \times$. So in this case $C$ *almost* has biproducts (except that the 0 object might not actually be representable).

The picture I have in mind is the string of adjoints $\amalg \dashv \Delta \dashv \times$, and the question "when can this adjoint string be extended further?", which leads to the question "if the adjoint string extends further, is it always (as in familiar examples) periodic of period 2?".

Comment: I believe $X \sqcup Y \to X \times Y$ always iso implies that the category is canonically enriched in commutative monoids (not just pointed sets). I don't know if this is helpful for you though.

Comment: Oh -- something I should have noticed. If there is a zero object (i.e. the nullary case holds), then if $\times$ is a left adjoint, it preserves the coproduct $(b,c) = (b,0) + (0,c)$. So $b \times c = (b+0) \times (0 + c) = (b \times 0) + (0 \times c) = b + c$. I suppose this morally answers the question in the affirmative, since it seems strange to consider the case where binary products admit a left adjoint but nullary products do not. But I'd be interested to see if this hypothesis can be lifted.

Comment: Another thing that may help is that such an $R$ will be a pseudo coassociative operation. In particular, if the terminal object is also initial, i.e. the $C \rightarrow C^0$ is a right adjoint to the terminal object $C^0 \rightarrow C$, the category $C$ will become a pseudocomonoid in Cat with comultiplication $R$ and counit  $C \rightarrow C^0$.  This should imply that $R$ is isomorphic to the diagonal.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've edited the first paragraph in an attempt to make the question clearer. Please revert if you don't like my edit. One answerer has misinterpreted the question, and although I think it's (logically) clear what you mean, I can see that switching between "being a left adjoint" and "having a left adjoint" could cause confusion.

Comment: Perhaps slightly relevant is https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2126, in which Steve Lack proved that having any natural isomorphism $X\sqcup Y \cong X\times Y$ implies semiadditivity (even with previously assuming zero objects).

Comment: I updated my answer below to actually answer the right question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the first question: Yes.

Let $C$ be a category with finite products and let $\Delta=(\Delta_1,\Delta_2):C\to C\times C$ s.t. $$\times\dashv \Delta.$$
More specifically we find $$[X\times Y, Z]\simeq[(X,Y),\Delta Z]=[X,\Delta_1 Z]\times[Y,\Delta_2 Z].$$ Note that this isomorphism is functorial in all arguments and given $f:X'\to X$ and $g:Y'\to Y$ we find the isomorphism to be compatible with precomposition with $(f,g)$ (I did not check this compatibility with much diligence so please take care here). Now, take $Y=*$ to be the final object (also the neutral object with respect to $\times$). We find $$[X,Z]\simeq[X,\Delta_1 Z]\times [*,\Delta_2 Z].$$
Taking $X=Z$ and we find $\varphi\in [Z,\Delta_1 Z]$ and $\omega\in [*,\Delta_2 Z]$ corresponding to the identity on $Z$. Conversely, taking $X=\Delta_1 Z$ we find $\phi\in[\Delta_1 Z, Z]$ corresponding to $(\mathrm{id}_{\Delta_1 Z},\omega)$. Now the compatibility with precomposition can be used to obtain $$\varphi\circ\phi=\mathrm{id}\textrm{ and } \phi\circ\varphi=\mathrm{id}.$$

I guess you'd still have to confirm that this actually constitutes an isotransformation $\mathrm{id}_C\simeq\Delta_1$.

Edit: After this, I guess we also find $*$ to not only be final but also initial as we arrive at $$(-,\omega):[X,Z]\simeq[X,Z]\times[*,Z].$$ So $[*,Z]=\{\omega\}$.

Comment: The OP is asking about *right* adjoints to the product functor, not *left* adjoints.

Comment: Fixed. The answer is still yes.

Comment: I think this does in fact give a correct answer (hence +1), although I'd make a few alterations. In place of "functorial" I'd say "natural". Furthermore, I think the punch line is easier to see by *first* recognizing that $[\ast, \Delta_2 Z]$ has just one element (which is obvious since the composite $[Z, Z] \cong [Z, \Delta_1 Z] \times [\ast, \Delta_2 Z] \stackrel{\text{proj}}{\to} [\ast, \Delta_2 Z]$, which is the constant function at $\omega$, is onto), so that the composite $[X, Z] \cong [X, \Delta_1 Z] \times [\ast, \Delta_2 Z] \stackrel{\text{proj}}{\cong} [X, \Delta_1 Z]$ is an iso.

Comment: (continued) Then finish off with Yoneda to conclude $\Delta_1 \cong Id$. Similarly, $\Delta_2 \cong Id$. This means $\Delta \cong (Id, Id)$ is the diagonal.

Comment: (But if you don't assume nullary products but only the existence of binary products, then you've knocked out the possibility of using this argument. It's debatable whether binary products only is a natural assumption! (-: )

Comment: I thought that the original question was intentionally pretty narrow, i.e., not assuming nullary products.

Comment: Yeah. Maybe the original question then should be rephrased as: "If $n$-ary products exist and $\prod^n\dashv\Delta$, do we then find $\Delta$ to be the $n$-ary diagonal?"

Answer (score 9):

Building on Garlef Wegart's work, the answer is yes in general. The idea is to show that if $C$ has a right adjoint to $\times$, then it is enriched in pointed sets, so that $C$ embeds fully faithfully in a category $C_\ast$ with a zero object and the easy argument can be applied. And as noted already, in this case $C$ will have biproducts with respect to a (necessarily unique) enrichment in pointed sets.

Suppose that $R= (R_1, R_2): C \to C \times C$ is right adjoint to $\times : C \times C \to C$. Then $\pi_1 : X \times Y \to X$ is natural in $X$ and $Y$. By adjointness, this corresponds to $\pi_{11}: X \to R_1 X$ and $\pi_{12}: Y \to R_2 X$ natural in $X$ and $Y$. Similarly, $\pi_2: Y \times X \to X$ gives us $\pi_{21} : Y \to R_1 X$ and $\pi_{22}: X \to R_2 X$. Thus we get $(\pi_{12}, \pi_{21}): Y \to R_2 X \times R_1 X$ natural in $X$ and $Y$, which we can compose (after swapping the factors) with the counit $R_1 X \times R_2 X \to X$ to obtain a map $Y \to X$, natural in $X$ and $Y$.

That is, $C$ admits a (necessarily unique) enrichment in pointed sets. So there is a canonical way to add a zero object, and the resulting inclusion $C \to C_\ast$ is fully faithful. Moreover, $C_\ast$ still has products, computed as in $C$ with $X \times 0 = 0 \times X = X$. One can extend $R$ by hand to a functor $R_\ast: C_\ast \to C_\ast \times C_\ast$ by setting $R_\ast(0) = (0,0)$, and then check by hand that $R_\ast$ is still right adjoint to $\times_{C_\ast}$. (Conceptually, zero objects are [absolute](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/absolute+colimit) for $\mathsf{Set}_\ast$-enrichment, and the forgetful functor from $\mathsf{Set}_\ast$-enriched categories to $\mathsf{Set}$-enriched categories creates products and adjunctions.)

Hence the argument I gave in the comments applies: $X \times Y = (X + 0) \times (0 + Y) = (X \times 0) + (0 \times Y) = X + Y$ in $C_\ast$, because $\times$, as a left adjoint, must preserve colimits (note that the coproduct $(X,0) + (0,Y) = (X,Y)$ holds automatically in $C_\ast$; we need not assume the existence of coproducts). Hence $\times_{C_\ast} = +_{C_\ast}$ and taking adjoints we have $R_\ast = \Delta_{C_\ast}$. By restricting along the fully faithful inclusion $C \to C_\ast$, we get $R= \Delta_C$ as desired.

Comment: I haven't checked, but this must be essentially the same argument in the Lack paper that Mike Shulman links to in the comments above.

Comment: Note to self: the soft argument can be seen as a consequence of Lemma 2.4.4 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7188). For the diagonal and the terminal map are the unit and counit of the self-duality of $C$ in the 2-category of categories and spans of functors. By the lemma, their right adjoints are themselves the unit and counit of an adjunction, and then the further right adjoints are also the unit and counit of an adjunction. But this last adjunction is between the same spans as the first one, so it must be isomorphic to the original diagonal / terminal map pair.

Comment: There's a subtlety in that last step: the unit and counit of an adjunction are only unique up to an automorphism of either the unit or counit. But the counit is a functor into the identity span on the terminal category, so it has no nontrivial automorphisms.